# Квалификация предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

«*Ему было семь лет.*»

Какое это предложение? Двусоставное неполное/полное? Односоставное?

Думаю, оно двусоставное полное. *Десять лет* (что?), *было* (что делало?). *Мне* (кому?) — дополнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ему было семь лет.**

**Двусоставное предложение**, предикативная основа: было семь лет, ему ― дополнение.

Из словаря:

**БЫТЬ**  5. (**в наст. вр. с опущением**). Наступать (о времени суток, года и т.п.). (Был) уже вечер. Был девятый день после смерти матери. Будет весна - на душе станет легче. Это (будет) начало Нового года. // **Находиться в каком-л. возрасте; исполняться, отмечаться** (о дате со дня рождения, основания, появления кого-, чего-л.). **Сыну (будет) скоро пять.** **Профессору (было) далеко за шестьдесят**. В 2003 г. (будет) трёхсотлетие со дня основания Петербурга.

Comment: @Аrina, это СИС? Я правильно поняла?

Comment: Я думаю, что семь лет - подлежащее, было - простое глагольное сказуемое. Было - это не связка. Сравнить: Ему исполнилось семь лет.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже так думала, но не была уверена.